# MySQL Query Issue with a Delete Query

Tags: php, mysql

I cannot fix this query
Tryed many times and i still get MySQL Syntax Error

```
//MySqli Delete Query
$mysqli->query("DELETE FROM `deliverys` WHERE id=" . $row['id'] . "");
```

What is wrong please?

Comment: and the error is "ask Stackoverflow"?

Comment: Better to use prepared statements

Comment: What is the value of `$row['id']` and what is the actual error message?

Comment: what is the error please? there could be an issue with the value of `$row['id']`

Comment: The query itself is fine, altho' you don't need the last concatenation, i.e. `. ""`. If you're getting a MySQL Syntax Error you should indicate the error message, error number and what version of MySQL that you're using.  Also what does your code look like that precedes this statement. So, help us help you by providing more specific information, please.

Answer (score 2):

Dude, do some rudimentary debugging here, echo out the SQL text you are submitting to the database.

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM `deliverys` WHERE id=" . $row['id'] ;
echo "SQL=" . $sql; 

if (!$mysqli->query($sql)) {
    echo "ERROR: " . $mysqli->error;
}
```

And test the statement against the database from a different client, verify that it's a valid SQL statement.

We can take some guesses at what the SQL Syntax error is, for example, if `$row['id']` evaluates to spaces or an empty string, we know that the SQL statement is going to be invalid. But we're really just guessing.  Maybe `$row['id']` evaluates to some other value that produces an invalid SQL statement.  (Maybe there's not a table named `deliverys`, or maybe the table doesn't contain a column named `id`, or maybe the user you're connecting as doesn't have privileges. Sometimes, the actual error message the MySQL returns will give you a clue as to what is wrong.)

There's not enough context here, but it looks as if your code here is subject to SQL Injection... much better to use a prepared statement with a bind placeholder.  Hopefully, there's some kind of guarantee that it won't ever evaluate to a value like **`1 OR 1=1`**.

Comment: you should add `trim()` and `mysql_real_escape_string()` to your answer to make it "better"

Comment: @vladkras: obviously, we wouldn't mix `mysqli_` and `msyql_` interface function calls, so no, I wouldn't add a `mysql_` interface function. And it's true that using "_escape_string" will mitigate some SQL Injection vulnerabilities, but my personal preference would be to follow the long standing best practice: **prepared statements** with **bind placeholders**. It's possible that OP has already validated that the value returned by `$row['id']` consists entirely of digit characters... I just couldn't post that code without shuddering, since it appears to be vulnerable to SQL Injection.

Comment: ... but we can't really tell, based on what OP has posted. Perhaps OP does intend for `$row['id']` to return a value of "`**1 OR id in (2,3,4)`**", or a value that includes single quotes "**`'bar'`**"... but that's all conjecture and assumption, OP hasn't provided enough context for us to tell. What OP is clearly missing is some rudimentary debugging skills.

Answer (score 0):

try to hard code value instead of using $row['id']. If it's working your $row['id'] variable is not set properly. make sure $row['id'] have a integer value by echo it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$mysqli->query("DELETE FROM deliverys WHERE id=".$row['id']);
```

Comment: Removing unnecessary spaces, removing an unnecessary concatenation of an empty string... that may be some improvement to the code... but how the *flip* does that answer the question OP asked?